# NavigationProgress doesn't show progressbar

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, navigation

I'm writing a WPF application using a navigation frame. I'm trying to display a progress-bar while waiting for a page to be loaded.

Like the [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx) sais:

> Navigating : Occurs when a new navigation is requested. Can be used to
>   cancel the navigation.
>
> NavigationProgress : Occurs periodically during a download to provide
>   navigation progress information.
>
> Navigated : Occurs when the page has been located and downloaded.

So I have a Grid (navigationStatusGrid) with ProgressBar (navigationProgressBar) and I have a Frame (mainFrame)

These are my event handlers:

```
private void mainFrame_NavigationProgress(object sender, NavigationProgressEventArgs e)
{
     long progress = e.BytesRead * 100 / e.MaxBytes;
     Console.WriteLine("Navigating progress:" + progress + "%");
     navigationProgressBar.Value = progress;
}

private void mainFrame_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
     Console.WriteLine("start navigating");
     mainFrame.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
     navigationStatusGrid.Visibility= Visibility.Visible;
}

private void mainFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     Console.WriteLine("end navigating");
     mainFrame.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
     navigationStatusGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

This is my output:

```
start navigating
Navigating progress:4%
Navigating progress:8%
...
Navigating progress:87%
Navigating progress:92%
Navigating progress:96%
Navigating progress:99%
Navigating progress:100%
Navigating progress:100%
end navigating
```

So you would say it works, but somehow the UI only gets updated when the page is loaded. The UI even freezes up while loading... I don't get to see the progressbar just instantly the loaded page. How do I solve this?

Comment: I can't even get the progress event to be fired for some reason...

Comment: mainFrame.Source = new Uri("Views/Home.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
where "Views/Home.xaml" is the Page I'm Loading.. Fires up the event for me, but I think there is some threading issue.. Like the navigation happens in the same thread as my UI or something..

Comment: @VDP Have you find any solution to show a progress to the user while loading the second page

Comment: @JMat Jup, I quit developing in C#  :-) no just kidding, it was a hobby project 4 years ago... Don't remember...sorry! The answer provided below wasn't a solution but I had to agree with him...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The progress event seems rather useless to me, while the documentation claims that the navigation happens assunchronously (if you use the `Navigate` method) i cannot make out just which part of it is supposed to be assynchronous.

If you have a large XAML that will freeze up the UI, if you have a long running contructor that will freeze up the UI as well and if you navigate to a web-page the progress event is not even fired.

At least some of this makes sense as controls are thread-afine, if the object were to be created asynchronously on a different thread that would cause problems. If you have a long running consctructor you need to externalize the work to a thread locally as the constructor itself needs to be called on the UI-thread.

Comment: I also struggle to implement a proper waiting progress while completes the navigation to new page. Do you have any other suggestions to implement a progress bar to show the start to end of loading a page ?

Comment: Sorry, no idea, usually don't use frames.